# How to prompt a user multiple times by a batch file with multiple user inputs?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, user-input

I want to change the serial number and product number of about 250 servers (they are not correct at the moment). I know the command that I need to use, but I need to be able to input certain options in to that command and then run it.

The options I need are:

1. A prompt for selecting the update of the serial or the product number
2. Multiple prompts for actual serial number, an IP address, a user name and password on having selected before the update of the serial number
3. Multiple prompts for actual product number, an IP address, a user name and password on having selected before the update of the product number

The command I wish to run via the batch file is:

```
asu64 set SYSTEM_PROD_DATA.SysInfoSerialNum XXXXXXX --host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX --user XXXX --password XXXX
```

The `XXX` is a user defined input. I'd also like for completion and then go back to the initial selection menu.

Here is what I have done so far. (Please excuse the simplicity of it. I am very new to this stuff.)

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Test Code
ECHO.
ECHO 1.Serial Number
ECHO 2.Product Name
ECHO.
CHOICE /C 12 /M "Enter your choice:"
ECHO.
IF CHOICE 1 GOTO SerialNumber
IF CHOICE 2 GOTO ProductName

:SerialNumber
ECHO Serial Number 
GOTO End

:ProductNumber
ECHO Product Number
GOTO End

PAUSE
```

Many thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be used for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "IpAddress="
set "NameUser="
set "Password="

:MainMenu
cls
echo(
echo   1 ... Serial number
echo   2 ... Product number
echo   E ... Exit
echo(
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12E /N /M "Enter your choice:"
if errorlevel 3 exit /B
if not errorlevel 1 goto MainMenu
echo(
if errorlevel 2 goto ProductNumber

set "NumberText=serial"
set "NumberOption=SYSTEM_PROD_DATA.SysInfoSerialNum"
goto NumberPrompt

:ProductNumber
set "NumberText=product"
set "NumberOption=SYSTEM_PROD_DATA.SysInfoProductNum"

:NumberPrompt
set "NumberValue="
set /P "NumberValue=Please enter %NumberText% number: " || goto NumberPrompt
set "NumberValue=%NumberValue:"=%"
if not defined NumberValue goto NumberPrompt

echo(
if defined IpAddress (set "Default= [%IpAddress%]") else set "Default="
:IpPrompt
set /P "IpAddress=Please enter IP address%Default%: "
if not defined IpAddress goto IpPrompt
set "IpAddress=%IpAddress:"=%"
if not defined IpAddress goto IpPrompt

echo(
if defined NameUser (set "Default= [%NameUser%]") else set "Default="
:NamePrompt
set /P "NameUser=Please enter user name%Default%: "
if not defined NameUser goto NamePrompt
set "NameUser=%NameUser:"=%"
if not defined NameUser goto NamePrompt

echo(
if defined Password (set "Default= [%Password%]") else set "Default="
:PasswordPrompt
set /P "Password=Please enter password%Default%: "
if not defined Password goto PasswordPrompt
set "Password=%Password:"=%"
if not defined Password goto PasswordPrompt

echo(
"%~dp0ASU64.exe" set %NumberOption% "%NumberValue%" --host "%IpAddress%" --user "%NameUser%" --password "%Password%"
echo(
if not errorlevel 1 (
       echo The update of the %NumberText% number "%NumberValue%" was successful.
) else echo ERROR: The update of the %NumberText% number "%NumberValue%" failed!
echo(
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C CE /N /T 10 /D C /M "Press C to continue or E to exit ..."
if not errorlevel 2 goto MainMenu
endlocal
```

The executable `ASU64.exe` is referenced with full path of the batch file which means the executable must be always in the same directory as the batch file. The current directory of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file does not matter in this case.

Please read the following answers for the explanation of the code:

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)
- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is the batch file path.
- `choice /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`